# Implementing generic interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following interface:

```js
interface Foo<T> {
  foo (value: T): void;
}
```

And I have a class which implements this interface:

```js
class FooString implements Foo<string> {
  foo (value) {
    value
  }
}
```

What caught my eye is that the compiler now complains about `value` being `implicitly typed as any`. Why is that? Shouldn't the interface enforce that it is of type `string`, since `T` is `string`?

Also, turning the interface to an (abstract) base class doesn't help. So, besides the question why this is – how can I "fix" this? IMHO implementing an interface should result in an *exact* implementation, not one which roughly matches?

Comment: as posted in the other answer this is not doable you need to type define it.

`class FooString implements Foo<string> {
  foo (value : string ) {
    value
  }
}`